# Why is new Enquue not being called?

Tags: c#

I am working on a .NET framework version, which does not have ConcurrentQueue support.
I wrote a simple class, which inherits from Generic.Queue and does a lock as shown below.
When I call my own implementation of ConcurrentQueue's Enqueue method, I don't see it being called
at all and its generic version that is being called. What am I doing wrong?

```
public class ConcurrentQueue<T> : Queue<T>
{
    private Object thisLock = new Object();
    new void Enqueue(T obj)
    {
        lock (thisLock)
        {
             base.Enqueue(obj);
        }
    }
    new T Dequeue()
    {
        lock (thisLock)
        {
             return base.Dequeue();
        }
    }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        int i = 5;
        ConcurrentQueue<int> cc = new ConcurrentQueue<int>();
        cc.Enqueue(i);

    }
}
```

Comment: Important note, if you fix your problem with not having public methods if I did `Queue<int> cc = new ConcurrentQueue<int>()` then did `cc.Enqueue(i)` your method would not be called. You might be better off inheriting from [`Queue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of `Queue<T>`. In fact it has a method `Queue.Synchronized` which generates a proxy that does exactly what you do in your above code.

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to make your methods **public**, methods are **private** by default.

```
public new void Enqueue(T obj)
{
     lock (thisLock)
     {
          base.Enqueue(obj);
     }
}
public new T Dequeue()
{
      lock (thisLock)
      {
           return base.Dequeue();
      }
 }
```

When I debug this code I can see it hits the `ConcurrentQueue<T>.Enqueue` method.